# The 'Database' with 'ID' = 'xxxxxxx' doesn't exist in the collection

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssas, tabular-model

I have a SSAS Tabular server with 30 database.

I also have a scheduled process to backup all databases daily.

When I run the process which is an SSIS package with script task using AMO, I get this error :

> The 'Database' with 'ID' = 'nameofdatabase' doesn't exist in the
>   collection.

The backup process is running under the service account credential and it successfully backs up 27 databases but fails for only 3 of them.

I checked those databases and don't see anything special on them.

I googled the error message and most of the issues are related to deploying or processing the database. I don't see any reason for failing the backup.

What is the problem and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Tom V](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194726/22336) mentioned I need to use Name instead of ID in my C# AMO code.

currently my code is

```
Server server = new Server();
server.Connect(@"data source=" + asServer);
Database db = server.Databases[dbName];
db.Backup(
    new BackupInfo
    {
        AllowOverwrite = true,
        ApplyCompression = true,
        File = fileName
    }
    );
```

`server.Databases[dbName]` searches the collection with **ID** of the database. To use **Name** for finding the database I need to use below code

```
Database db = server.Databases.FindByName(dbName);
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing that could cause this is if you use the `Name` of the database instead of the `ID`.

For example, I created a database with with the name `Demo1`, so the ID defaulted to the same string.

Afterwards I renamed the database, but that doesn't change the ID.

If your AMO script uses the name string instead of the ID string that could cause this error.

[image]